# Are absolute newbies welcome?

Tags: discussion, scope

I see that the site is for enthusiasts and power users. But are absolute newbies welcome to ask beginner questions?

I hope I'm not completely in the wrong place, I meant newbie programmers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Newbies, as in people that are new to using Android, are welcome here.

Newbie questions about using Android are welcome here (as long as they haven't been asked and answered already here).

Programming questions of any kind, even newbie programming questions, are not welcome here.

Comment: As far as I know there's no specific Android Programming SE, but there is an [Android section on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info).

Answer (score 12):

While *newbie users* are of course welcome (but encouraged to search before re-asking an already existing question), and *programmers* per se are also welcome, **programming questions** are not – as you can easily find out in our [Help Center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:
>
> - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android))

Answer (score -11):

newbies should always newb out on tutorials, stickies and Google before cluttering forums

Comment: Primary error: This is not, and never has been, a forum.