# Why "regular people" are not welcome in the tour?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Is this is a mistake or a deliberate move that the terms "*regular people*" are not mentioned in the [tour](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour) ([record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unyzz.png)) of the site? As of now it currently notes:

> **Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system.

On the other hand, in the page [what topics can I ask about here?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ([record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G3YP.png)), one gets to see:

> **Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange** is for enthusiasts, power users, and ***regular people*** who use the Android operating system.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

Moreover, the said help center page now makes me wonder why do we not simply write:

> **Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange** is for users of Android operating system.

Per [this question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/201/96277), I conclude that the terms "*regular people*" have been there for quite a long time, but I'm not sure whether the question notes the mention of the same in help center or tour in particular.

"*Regular people*" are also welcome on this site per [this post](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1687/96277), so I don't see why the terms are missing from the tour?

Surprisingly, [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) shares the same problem in [help center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and in [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Yeah, probably an oversight that occurred when the tour page was originally rolled out. Changing it to simply "...users of the Android operating system" or even just "Android users" is probably a good idea.

Comment: Other possibility: because everything starts from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) a site for "*professional and enthusiast programmers*". IMO, the "enthusiast" part was meant to filter out the "newbie who doesn't know & care about manual/user guide and just ask question" (well. that's a problem on bigger sites like SO, but not so much on here)

Comment: @AndrewT. could be  [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour) as well.

Comment: @Meta It is. I'll wait a little to see if anyone has wording opinions, but then we can update it without having to get SE involved.

Comment: On a lighter note- one [usage](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=regular+meaning&oq=regular+m&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.7425j0j4&client=ms-android-huawei&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8) of *regular* is *not pretentious or arrogant; ordinary and friendly*, so it may be a subtle hint on "how to behave".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've updated the tour and help center to both use the phrasing "users of the Android operating system".

I also took this opportunity to split out the section of the help center article that notes that development-related questions are off-topic. I don't know if it will make any meaningful difference, but it is certainly much more prominent now:

> ### What if I have a question about Android development?
>
> Development/programming questions are not covered on this site. You can visit our sister site, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), instead.

Answer (score 8):

This is likely a result of how [Area 51 instructs users proposing a new site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology).

> We're creating sites for experts.
>
> Your site should focus on pilots, not passengers; lawyers, not lawbreakers; professional photographers, not Uncle Marv with his digital point-n-shoot.
>
> If the site can attract the experts, the amateur enthusiasts will follow!

So, the box "This site is for ____" gets filled accordingly, and then used for the tour of the site.

Regular folks arrive later and eventually become the majority of visitors. At this point the tour may need an update.